# Unable to fetch IIS status from Remote server using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch IIS status from remote server using powershell.
I have used command Get-Service but i don't recieve any output from this command.
Below is my code block.

```
$pass='pass'|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
$Credentials =  New-Object   
System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("user",$pass);
$Service=invoke-command -computername "server" -credential $Credentials - 
scriptblock {Get-Service|Where-Object Name -eq 'IISADMIN'}
if($Service.Status -eq 'Running')
{
write-host "IIS Running"
}
else
{
 throw "IIS not running or Not installed"

}
```

Comment: What is Windows Server version? If it is Win 2008 R2, IIS service is actually called: **W3SVC (World Wide Web Publishing Service)** - Just look for this service, instead of 'IISADMIN'

Answer (score 0):

I Checked your code and did not see any problem with it, Did you checked the service exists locally using `Get-Service` or Service Manager?

Anyway you don't have to use `Invoke-Command` for this, you can use the built in `-ComputerName` parameter of the `Get-Service` cmdlet,

And if you need to provide credentials, you can use WMI:

```
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $encrypted)
$Service = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName Server -Filter 'Name = "W3SVC"' -Credential $Credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a WMI call instead, I have found it far more reliable when working with remote servers.

$Service = Get-WmiObject -Computername $computer -Credential $credentials Win32_service -ErrorAction Continue | Where {$_.Name -eq 'IISADMIN'}